# Find $f(i)$ for an entire function satisfying given conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function satisfying $|f''(z) - 3|\geq 0.001$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $f(0)=0$, $f(1) = 2$, and $f(-1) = 4.$ Find $f(i)$.

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this...

If we try a polynomial of degree 2, $f(z) = az^2 + bz + c$, where $a,b,c$ are constants, then the above constraints on $f$ force $c = 0$, $a = 3$, and $b = -1$. In this case we find that $f(i) = -3 - i$.

Does the condition $|f''(z) - 3|\geq 0.001$ force $f$ to be a polynomial of degree 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider  $g=\frac{1}{f''-3}$ and [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) .

Comment: Ohh I see... then $g$ is entire and bounded, hence constant so that $f''(z)$ is constant which shows that $f^{(n)}(z) = 0$ for $n\geq 3$ so $f$ is a polynomial of degree 2.

Comment: @Pete: Yes, well done!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see this is to note that $f''(z)$ is an entire analytic function that omits an uncountable number of values (a small interval around $3$). Then by [Picard's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), the function must be constant.

The method in the other answer is more elementary, but this is the way I approached the problem. Knowledge of Picard's theorem allows you to do it without expending any effort.

Comment: Oh nice, I really like this.